# Azure with Windows server 2012 r2

Tags: azure, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

When using Azure VM, I have a windows server 2012 r2 running can i use that active directory without being charged? Do i have to use Azure Active Directory? Just want to make sure before i do anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Azure Active Directory or Active directory according to your requirements. Before choose, you need to understand what is the differences between Active Directory on Premise and in the Cloud. I think [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrisavis/2013/04/24/active-directory-differences-between-on-premise-and-in-the-cloud/) will helpful. Azure Active Directory has three edition, refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) to know the detailed pricing. As I know, on premise active directory will not incur fee.